# Set multiple filters onclick by using indexOf Method - not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to filter some elements by clicking on a button. The filters can be combined. The elements may contain multiple filters in a data-attribute, comma-separated.

My HTML

```
<div class="filterbar">
<button data-filter="filter1"></button>
<button data-filter="filter2"></button>
<button data-filter="filter3"></button>
</div>

<div class="div"  data-filter-category="filter1, filter2"></div>
<div class="div" data-filter-category="filter2"></div>
<div class="div" data-filter-category="filter3"></div>
```

My Js:

```
   document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     if (e.target.closest('button')) {


         e.target.classList.toggle('active');

         // Returns an array with active filters 
        var activeFilters = document.querySelectorAll('.active');
        var categories = [];
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(activeFilters, function(activeFilter) {
            categories.push(activeFilter.getAttribute('data-filter'));
        });

       var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.div');

       Array.prototype.forEach.call(allDivs, function(div) {
         // Build an array of filter-attributes
         var categoryArr = div.getAttribute('data-filter-category').split(',');

         for (var i = 0; i < categoryArr.length; i++){
                if (categories.indexOf(categoryArr[i]) > -1) {
                   div.classList.add('filtered');
                }
            }
       });
    }
}, false);
```

This is not working. By click on button 2 with filter attribute "filter2" i expected 2 divs to have class "filtered". div 1 which has filter 2 and div 2 which also has filter2 asl data-attribute.

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute of `filter1, filter2`, when split on by a comma, will produce `'filter'` and `' filter2'` - you need another space. You can also signficaintly slim down your code by using spread syntax and `.map` to get the categories, and then you can use `classList.toggle`'s second argument to either enable or disable the class, depending on whether the div being iterated over has a category in the set:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.closest('button')) return;
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  
  const categories = new Set(
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.active')]
      .map(filter => filter.getAttribute('data-filter'))
  );
  for (const div of document.querySelectorAll('.div')) {
    const thisDivCats = div.getAttribute('data-filter-category').split(', ');
    div.classList.toggle('filtered', thisDivCats.some(cat => categories.has(cat)));
  }
});
```

```css
.filtered {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="filterbar">
  <button data-filter="filter1">click</button>
  <button data-filter="filter2">click</button>
  <button data-filter="filter3">click</button>
</div>

<div class="div" data-filter-category="filter1, filter2">1, 2</div>
<div class="div" data-filter-category="filter2">2</div>
<div class="div" data-filter-category="filter3">3</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much CertainPerformance! I am ashamed because the error now seems to be obvious! Thanks also a lot for your perfect js code. Unfortunately i have to write the code in JavaScript ES5 but i will check out if there is a way to transpile the code so i can use your prerfect small piece of code ;) Thank you!!